# how many days will app hub take to sign a windows phone app after submitting it?

Tags: windows-phone-7, app-hub

how many days will app hub take to sign a windows phone app after submitting it ? Does anyone have any personal experience regarding this? Whats the maximum number of days taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a number of factors which dictate how long an application will take to pass certification such as :-

1. Complexity
2. Regions and number of regions submitted to
3. Number of other apps waiting for certification

So this isn't a straightforward question to answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN, [Certification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202928%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) of your app usually takes "on average" 5 business days